# Using a multi check box to add various items with the same id to a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox that has a list of topics. After my user has registered they can select a list of topics which are then put into a table. At the moment i have the code to find their member_id and add it into the table. But i'm not sure how to process the topics the user chooses and then add it into the interest table with the users member_id.

I know i need to use a for loop to process through the member_id and the topic_id and add each one choosen into the table. But i'm not sure how to do this. Here is my code.

This my form

```
</form>
            <form method="post" action="topic.php">
            <input type="checkbox" name="topic[]" value="1"> artificial intelligance
            <input type="checkbox" name="topic[]" value="2"> computer graphics
            <input type="checkbox" name="topic[]" value="3"> computer animation
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit topic">
</form>
```

These two find the member_id and the topic_id

// find member id

```
$query = "SELECT member_id FROM member where username = '$un'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("query failed: " . mysql_error());        
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $username=$row['member_id'];

//find the topic id 
$query = "SELECT topic_id FROM topic WHERE topic_name ='$interest'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("query failed: " . mysql_error());        
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $topic_id=$row['topic_id'];
```

Comment: Correct me if am wrong .... You need to know who to process your form to save the information in your database where topic can be one or many  ???

Comment: I want to know how i can save the member_id and topic_id into a table, but the user can select many topics, so i would need to be able to insert many records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

**Assumptions**

A. Member ID is Integer

B. Table was created like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selectedtopic` (
  `selectedID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topicID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `selectedStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`selectedID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Sample Code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `stackoverflow`.`selectedtopic` (
`selectedID` ,
`memberID` ,
`topicID` ,
`selectedStatus`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '%d',  '%d',  '%d');" ;

foreach($_POST['topic'] as $selected)
{
    mysql_query(sprintf($sql,$username,$selected,1)) ;
}
```

Left me know if you need any more help

Comment: What does sprintf and the variable $selected do?

Comment: and is $_POST['topic'] accessing the array i set up?

Comment: At the moment i have this code checking wether an interest has been posted.

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for documentation on `sprintf` ` $_POST['topic']` is the array you set up and ` $selected` each each array broken to individual component

Comment: Ok thanks, what does %d mean? should the value not be $username and $selected ?

Comment: I cant show you my code it still isnt working is there any way i can message you?